# Designing an easily extensible library - can this design be improved?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, rbac

I would appreciate some feedback on the design I am thinking of implementing for a RBAC subsystem in a library I am designing. The class names and a brief description is provided in the table below:

```
Name                      Description
User                      Abstract Base Class (so it can't be instantiated)
IRole                     Interface
Role                      Implements IRole
RoleCollection            Collection of roles
Personnel                 ABC. Represents a user in the system. Derives from User, delegates to (i.e. has-a) collection of roles (RoleCollection)
PersonnelFactory          Creates specific personnel types
```

Some examples of personnel created by the **PersonnelFactory**:

```
SystemAdminPersonnel        
AccountsPersonnel
... etc
```

I want to partition roles into discrete classes, where dedicated custom role classes (that implement the IRole interface) perform specific functions. That is to say that for example:

The **SystemAdminRole** could have the following methods:

```
clearSystemCache();
createNewCache();
... etc.
```

Whilst the **AccountsRole** could have the following methods:

```
updateUserAccount();
getAccountBalance();
addAmountToAccountBalance();
 ... etc
```

Ideally, I would like to have the system display the following attributes:

1. Ability to add new functionality to a role, without having to modify the code. I intend to do this by using either (a) scripting (b) callable stored procedure
2. When I add a new method to a role, I would like Personnel objects that have that role to be able to 'automagically' perform the new functionality, without having to recompile the code.

For what its worth, this is a system component that I have needed in many projects - once I have the correct design, I envisage implementing the code in the following languages (different projects): Java, Python, Ruby (and possibly, PHP, C++), however, I want to get the system design correct first (along with desired attributes mentioned above), without having to depend on constructs provided by the language the system is implemented in.

Any advice on how to improve or modify the design above to get the desired functionality (extensibility without needing re-coding) will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are not a lot of responses now, I am just going to give you an abstract answer. Maybe this can help others contribute too.

**Database**

*"Abilities"* Table containing

> Column Main: Abilities name that is hard coded and never can be changed.

*"Roles"* Table Containing

> Column FK: Abilities Table PK as Foriegn Key
>
> Column Main: Some Hard Coded code that will never change and can never duplicate per role.

**Classes**

```
**ThousandClassParent** Class
-Array Abilities
-Constant Variable RoleName
-Meat(Ithinkthisabilityexists string)

**OneOfAThousandClass** Class Inherits *ThousandClassParent*
-Constructor()

**Helper** Static Class
-Array Abilities

-Constructor
-DebugValidate(Ithinkthisabilityexists string)
-Validate(Ithinkthisabilityexists string, ThousandClassParent.Abilities)
-PassesRunThis(Ithinkthisabilityexists string)
-FailsRunThis(Ithinkthisabilityexists string)
```

On each of your thousand classes with each representing a role (OneOfAthousand class), their parent will be ThousandClassParent Class.
On Constructor of OneOfAThousand class, ThousandClassParent.RoleName stores table Roles.Main (you will never change this again or in database unless role obsolete)
After that, call a stored procedure that uses ThousandClassParent.RoleName to filter and pick the right "abilities" from the "roles" table and store
them in ThousandClassParent.Abilities.
When you add a functionality to that role - User will have to restart to pick re initiate the class OneOfAThousandClass - no need to recompile code.

So there is a cue whether to run an ability and it depends on the user role, you both have them so then what?
Interface is okay. I would just do less. All thousand classes can "use" a call to a helper static class.
That static class on constructor can take the list of "abilities" in the abilities table.

As the user is linked with the role class, it will run from time to time the meat function from ThousandClassParent and pass a parameter which represents the ability to access.

So it will be something like this for function **ThousandClassParent.Meat**

```
if (DebugValidate(Ithinkthisabilityexists string))
{
    if (Validate(Ithinkthisabilityexists string, ThousandClassParent.Abilities))
    PassesRunThis(Ithinkthisabilityexists string)
    else 
    FailsRunThis(Ithinkthisabilityexists string)
}
else
{
SystemError
}
```

DebugValidate just checks if that ability really exists in database. Unless you are very confident, it is good to catch those errors.
That static class can have a validation function that returns true or false if class role abilities array passed contains the ability.
You call a different function if it passes and a different function if it does not pass with the parameter as the ability. Sometimes you do more stuff if it does not pass than when it pass.
Those 2 function will be similar: they will call the stored procedure or the filename template and   on the server which exists as the same name as the variable ability + post-prefix "fail"/"success". You will need to translate the template
to real programming code in the code. I guess trying to abstract that too will be too complicated and it is a more general subject than RBAC systems which you can ask it as a separate question.